# hook_theme not being called

Tags: drupal-6

I have a custom module called tf_decor. I never see the debug statement and I'm not sure why. I've tried clearing the cache (admin/settings/performance), but it did not help. Basically what I am trying to do it put a table inside a form.

```
function tf_decor_order_form($form_state)
{
  //form elements
}
```

function theme_tf_decor_order_form($form)
{
  watchdog(WATCHDOG_DEBUG, "HERE 2"); //This is NOT being called
}

function tf_decor_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) { 
  watchdog(WATCHDOG_DEBUG, "HERE 1"); //This is being called
  return array(
    'tf_decor_order_form' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 6 I had the same problem and the usual solution is to clear the caches. But this solution didn't solve it for me.

I use different files for my module code. These files were called in hook_menu() in my .module file. Within these files I had the theme hook function 'theme_tf_decor_order_form($form)' as you use it. It did not get called.

The solution was to move only this function: function theme_tf_decor_order_form($form) to the .module file. Cleared the caches and it worked.